# In which case AsynkTaskLoader uses cache data?

Tags: android, caching, android-loader, asynctaskloader

I am learning about the `Loader` and its implementation with `AsynkTaskLoader`.

In many examples I have seen that in the AsynkTaskLoader's `onStartLoading`method  is where the `cache` is checked, and if it is not null the result is delivered directly. However, this method is only called the first time the `Loader` is 
initiated, since for example when the device configuration changes and the `Loader` is initiated again from Activity's `OnCreate` method the `Loader` call directly `onLoadFinished` method.

To better understand the functionally of the `Loader` I would like to know how I can recreate a case where the cache is used.

Here some example code:

```
 static class ExampleAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String>{
    String mCacheData;
    Bundle mArgs;

    ExampleAsyncTaskLoader(Context context, Bundle args) {
        super(context);
        mArgs = args;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
            /* If no arguments were passed, we don't have a query to perform. Simply return. */
        if (mArgs == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mCacheData != null){
            deliverResult(mCacheData);
        }else {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String loadInBackground() {

            /* Extract the search query from the args using our constant */
        String searchQueryUrlString = mArgs.getString(SEARCH_QUERY_URL_EXTRA);

            /* If the user didn't enter anything, there's nothing to search for */
        if (searchQueryUrlString == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(searchQueryUrlString)) {
            return null;
        }

            /* Parse the URL from the passed in String and perform the search */
        try {
            URL githubUrl = new URL(searchQueryUrlString);
            return NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(githubUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(String data) {
        mCacheData = data;
        super.deliverResult(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the Activity is destroyed and recreated (as in configuration change) if the Loader data is ready - you'll receive it via the deliverResult.
However, In the case of Activity pause and then resume - the default behavior is to re-fetch the data, This is when the "local cache" makes sense.